# Something is disastrously wrong with my neural network and what it's produced

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, gan

I just got a neural network to run and although it doesn't raise any exceptions, I'm left with a horrible mess after 80 to 100 epochs:

After 100 epochs with the adapted code: [image: After 100 epochs]

After 100 epochs with the original code: [image: After 100 epochs]

I am trying to generate a grid of synthetic images of cats from my own database of cat photos that I compiled using a crawler. I am using an adapted code originally intended for the MNSIT handwritten digits database (hence the shape of the grid).

The network doesn't appear to be training, generating or discriminating properly because the epochs aren't taking long at all and what is being produced is very poor.

To be clear, I've tried to adapt another author's code that I found online and I've added other snippets of code to try to get it to work. It's evident that my 'FrankenNet' has fallen to bits and my 'bolt it together and see what happens' approach has its limitations.

Maybe I haven't loaded in the data correctly or perhaps there are a few other issues such as converting the data to a numpy array?

I'd love some advice because I really want to generate something and I've spent a long time trying to work it out through trial and error with no results. I'd especially appreciate some specific suggestions about what lines I need to change, add or remove to get this beast up to scratch.

Firstly, I have removed keras.datasets because I am not working with their database.

Original code:

```
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras.datasets import mnist
```

Adapted GAN:

```
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras.optimizers import Adam
```

This is how the data is loaded from MNIST in the original GAN:

```
def load_minst_data():
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    x_train = (x_train.astype(np.float32) - 127.5)/127.5
    x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784)
    return (x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test)
```

And this is what I have replaced it with to try to load and train my own JPGs:

```
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image as PImage

def loadImages(path):
    # return array of images
    imagesList = listdir(path)
    loadedImages = []
    for image in imagesList:
        img = PImage.open(path + image)
        loadedImages.append(img)
    return loadedImages

DATASET_NAME = 'catscats'
ROOT_DIR = '/Users/Darren/desktop'
DATASET_DIR = f'{ROOT_DIR}/{DATASET_NAME}'
 input_files = [os.path.join(dp, f) for dp, dn, fn in 
 os.walk(os.path.expanduser(f'{DATASET_DIR}/processed')) for f in fn
               if f != '.DS_Store']
imgs = np.ndarray(shape=(len(input_files), 100, 100, 3),
                  dtype=np.int)
for i, input_file in enumerate(input_files):
    # print('processing file: {}'.format(input_file))
    image = imread(input_file)
    imgs[i] = image
    # your images in an array
    imgs = loadImages(path)

 def loadImages():
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = input_file
    x_train = (x_train.astype(np.float32) - 127.5) / 127.5
    x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784)
    return (x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test)
```

Comment: Hi Darren!  to help troubleshoot it would be helpful to point to what you used as the template/starting point.  I would hope what you show us would be a _working_  combination of code+data or just data (if the code is identical to what you have above except for data paths) . Then we can help you to spot what might be the reason the _cats_ data does _not_ work.

Comment: Hi! As a starting point, I used this [tutorial and code](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/generative-adversarial-networks). 

I was able to successfully generate 200 epochs of MNSIT handwritten digits using this model.

Comment: did you change anything in the code besides the data paths?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have edited the post to include the original code which uses "def load_minst_data()" function to load JPGs. What I want to do is try to adapt this code which works and load in my own test/train data instead of the MNSIT database but I can't seem to do it.

Comment: The easiest way for a reader to help is if you point out specifically the code differences: you can annotate by using comments and then show only the section of code that differs -_not_ having two separate and complete code listings .

Comment: Understood, sorry I wasn't helpful with my original post. I have edited it to include the key differences between the original and adapted codes.

Comment: Looks good as a question now.  I will look more late tomorrow.

Comment: Okay, thanks very much,